# MySQL: GROUP BY custom date interval

Tags: mysql, sql

Situation: a table where every minute X energy device saves its consumption. I have to calculate the daily consumption (at hourly intervals, 00 - 01 - 02 - 03 - 04 ..... 23) of a single device on a certain day (to create a simple consumption hourly chart).

```
id | date                |  total | id_device
---------------------------------------------
0  | 2018-10-01 00:01:00 | 100    | 1
---------------------------------------------
1  | 2018-10-01 00:01:00 | 101    | 2
---------------------------------------------
2  | 2018-10-01 00:02:00 | 110    | 1
---------------------------------------------
3  | 2018-10-01 00:02:00 | 105    | 2
---------------------------------------------
.. | 2018-10-01 23:59:00 | 200    | 1
---------------------------------------------
.. | 2018-10-01 23:59:00 | 1000   | 2
```

I did this to calculate the **hourly consumption**

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(HOUR(`date`) < 10 , '0','') , HOUR(`date`)) AS `HH`, (MAX(`total`) - MIN(`total`)) AS `total` 
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') AND id_device = ?
GROUP BY `HH`
```

**Result**

```
HH | total
----------
00 | 100
01 | ...
.. | ...
23 | ...
```

This query correctly returns the totals (if an hour has no save it is not displayed in the query, no problem).

But the GROUP BY works in the following way

- 00 interval : 00:00 - 00:59
- 01 interval : 01:00 - 01:59
- 02 interval : 02:00 - 02:59
- ....
- 23 interval : 23:00 - 23:59

But I need this, otherwise the time calculation is incorrect.

- 00 interval : 23:59 (previous day) - 00:59
- 01 interval : 00:59 - 01:59
- 02 interval : 01:59 - 02:59
- ....
- 23 interval : 22:59 - 23:59

Is it possible to have this kind of intervals?

---

#### PS

For the case 00, I know I have to change the search starting from the last value recorded the day before, but that's not my problem now. I would do it that way:

```
WHERE 'date' BETWEEN 
  COALESCE((SELECT 'date' FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'date' < DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 1), DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

---

### UPDATE

DB Fiddle example. There are 3 devices, every single device has 5 days of record.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddvVguupi74TQjQ6yWJUzB/3

**Actual result** (id_device 1 , date 2018-10-03):

```
HH  total
00  354
01  354
02  354
03  354
04  354
05  354
06  354
07  354
08  354
09  354
10  354
11  354
12  354
13  354
14  354
15  354
16  354
17  354
18  354
19  354
20  354
21  354
22  354
23  354
```

**Expected result** :

```
HH  total
00  360
01  360
02  360
03  360
04  360
05  360
06  360
07  360
08  360
09  360
10  360
11  360
12  360
13  360
14  360
15  360
16  360
17  360
18  360
19  360
20  360
21  360
22  360
23  360
```

Comment: When you say "saves its consumption" is that the instant consumption at that moment, the total consumption since the last save, or the total consumption since some point in time, like midnight? YOur example data shows an ever increasing consumption y'see

Comment: Total is a continuously increasing value

Comment: So in any given hour, the consumption for that hour is the max recorded consumption value minus the min recorded consumption?

Comment: Yes `(MAX('total') - MIN('total')) AS 'total'`

Comment: The interval ends, which of them are included, which are excluded?

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @CaiusJard 10.1.32-MariaDB

Comment: Ahh.. gutting.. This would be much easier in 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot simpler:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(DATE(`date`), INTERVAL HOUR(`date`) HOUR) as date_hour,
  MAX(`value`) -
  COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ta.`value`) FROM test ta WHERE ta.id < MIN(t.id)),0) as this_hour_consumption
FROM
  test t
GROUP BY
  DATE_ADD(DATE(`date`), INTERVAL HOUR(`date`) HOUR);
```

How it works:

- Strips off the minutes and seconds from the time, reducing every date to just the date and the hour
- Finds the max consumption in that hour
- Finds the max consumption value whose id is less than the min id in the hour (i.e. the max consumption value from the previous hour
- Subtracts the max consumption this hour from the max consumption last hour to give the consumption for this hour

There are other ways to skin this cat:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(DATE(a.`date`), INTERVAL HOUR(a.`date`) HOUR) the_hour,
  SUM(a.`value` - b.`value`) sum_consumption_this_hour
FROM 
  test a INNER JOIN test b on a.id = b.id + 1
GROUP BY
  DATE_ADD(DATE(a.`date`), INTERVAL HOUR(a.`date`) HOUR);
```

This works by:

- join the data to itself on id = id-1 (gets you a "this" table and a "previous" table)
- work out the change in consumption between successive records (this.value - previous.value)
- and then group them up by the hour (same technique as above, reduce the datetime to a date, and add on the HOUR()s ) and sum them

Edit:

Modified the first query to work with your revised sample data:

```
SELECT 
  LPAD(HOUR(`date`), 2, '0') as date_hour,
  MAX(`total`) -
  COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ta.`total`) FROM test ta WHERE ta.id < MIN(t.id) and ta.id_device = t.id_device),0) as this_hour_consumption
FROM
  test t
WHERE 
  DATE(`date`) = '2018-10-03' and id_device = 1 --or DATE BETWEEN x AND y if this form doesn't use your index...
GROUP BY
  LPAD(HOUR(`date`), 2, '0');
```

The significant change is: added a WHERE clause to restrict the rows to just the subset day and device. Coordinated the select max() to consider the device too

Also reformatted the hour output, but that's cosmetic

Edit2: 
Here's another way to do it, simulating the LAG function (upgrade to MySQL 8!)

```
SET @prev=(SELECT MAX(`total`) FROM test WHERE id_device = 1 and DATE(`date`) < '2018-10-03');
SELECT
  date_hour,
  SUM(curr_tot - prev_tot) as hour_consumption
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    LPAD(HOUR(`date`), 2, '0') as date_hour,
    @prev as prev_tot,
    @prev:=`total` as curr_tot
  FROM
    test t
  WHERE 
    DATE(`date`) = '2018-10-03' and id_device = 1 /*or DATE BETWEEN x AND y if it uses your index...*/
  ORDER BY
    `date`
) a
GROUP BY
  date_hour;
```

- We get the max total from the previous date for that device and store it to a variable
- We pull the records from the table for the desired date, order them, then skip through them first outputting the variable contents (which for any given row is the previous row's value) then updating the variable to this row total (and it gets output after assignment)
- This gives a subquery that for every row shows the current total and the previous total. We subtract them to give the delta, and group/sum the deltas, per hour

Comment: I have an index on this table, with the columns date and id_device. So i think these solutions would not take advantage of the index. The table contains millions of records.

Comment: Might not be a great idea to index the date, to be honest - it's unique and highly selective so it's no better at selecting rows than the primary key. Index the hour and the device if you want a useful index for these. Also, theorize not when it comes to performance: test instead - if you're summarizing an entire table and the optimizer realises it's going to have to read every row anyway, it'll ignore the index (it's a performance hit to use an index to look up the rows you need to access, then access those rows, when you know you have to access all rows anyway)

Comment: The date is not unique in the table. In the table there are a lot of device (id_device). Every minute, every device save the consumption.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't heed the device either. These queries use all the source data because that is what was provided (and you only provided data from one device) and what is needed to summarise. If you're adding a WHERE (my queries don't feature a WHERE but nothing stops you adding it/it will be necessary to add if youre not sumamrising all the table) to restrict the rows to just a certain date range and device, why do you think it will ignore the index?

Comment: (Put these queries into your fiddle, and you'll see they work. If you then complain they don't work unmodified on all the table data, that's because you didn't provide a good representative sample and clearly state what you wanted out of it)

Comment: It's not a good update, to be honest; you haven't updated the sample data, haven't updated the "desired results", and the "desired results" you've put in the question cannot be generated by the sample data given. Please overhaul the entire question otherwise all you'll have is 3 annoyed professionals who were willing to help but are now bored/tired of the goalposts being constantly shifted and they'll move onto other questions

Comment: PS: I'm also updating the sample data

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`MINUTE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) function, you can determine if the minute value is 59.
- If it is equal to 59, you can increment the hour value to consider by 1.
- Use [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function instead to add leading '0', upto maximum string size of 2.

You can use the following to determine `HH`:

```
LPAD(IF(
        MINUTE(`date`) = 59, 
        HOUR(`date`) + 1, 
        HOUR(`date`)
       ), 
     2, 
     '0'
    ) AS `HH`
```

But, the problem in hand is that you have clashing rows for two groups at 59 minutes.
For eg: a row at **01:59:23** has to be considered in the `01` as well as `02` group. 
With a simple group by it is not possible. So, one approach is consider two different 
`Select` statements to get `HH` value for a row. One select will consider the original hour value, 
and another would consider `hour + 1` for 59 minute case. But then, we will have duplicates 
for all the other minutes (except 59th minute). This duplicate problem can be solved by 
utilizing [`Union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) statement.

Afterwards, you can use the **Unionized** result-set as a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and do a simple `Group By`.

So, you can try the following (you will still have to handle the edge cases when a day changes):

```
SELECT 
  dt.HH, 
  (MAX(dt.total) - MIN(dt.total)) AS total 
FROM
    (
      SELECT LPAD(IF(MINUTE(t1.date) = 59, HOUR(t1.date) + 1, HOUR(t1.date)), 2, '0') AS HH, 
             t1.total 
      FROM mytable AS t1
      WHERE t1.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND
                            DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')

      UNION 

      SELECT LPAD(HOUR(t2.date), 2, '0') AS HH, 
             t2.total 
      FROM mytable AS t2
      WHERE t2.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND
                            DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
    ) AS dt
GROUP BY dt.HH
```

Comment: Also with your solution i have different results.. and HH is not correct https://imgur.com/a/KVt7dCq

Comment: @WhiteLine there was a stupid typo at my end. parameters were in wrong order in the usage of `LPAD` function. Please check the edited answer now.

Comment: Ok now the HH is correct, but the totals are not correct. Have you look my the data example? thank you

Comment: @WhiteLine can you please create a SQL Fiddle / DB Fiddle, so that I can play with it.

Comment: @WhiteLine thanks. Can you tell me one specific `HH` value where total is not correct. What should be the expected value ?

Comment: Yes sure. For example , the 01 HH. The correct should be 61

Comment: @WhiteLine Please check the updated answer. Sure to work now :-)

Comment: Testing with online data it seems that now the sums are calculated correctly! But unfortunately, by modifying the WHERE as described in my question, i think there will still be to change.

Comment: @WhiteLine what modifications needed with where conditions ?

Comment: This `WHERE 'date' BETWEEN 
  COALESCE((SELECT 'date' FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'date' < DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 1), DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')`. If i found a value before 00:00:00 i have to use the date of this value as a starting value, otherwise i keep the 00:00:00 as the start value

Comment: This condition is necessary for a correct 00 interval.

Comment: @WhiteLine it is doable. Will require slight modifications in the Union between the two select statements. You may give it a try on your own. Let me know if still stuck. If this answer helped you, and put you in a right direction, you may kindly consider it accepting (green tick) and upvote as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i will try to include this last condition

Comment: By doing other checks I realized that the totals could be wrong, if, for example, some recordings should be missing.

Comment: It is not always said that the recordings are there every minute.

Comment: @WhiteLine it should not matter in my opinion. Under what sample data is the case failing ?

Comment: Try here : [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3NqENDcfamsX4nKgjLvHx/1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3NqENDcfamsX4nKgjLvHx/1), the interval 11 (for id_device 1), should be 378.

Answer (score 0):

Just shift your `date` column by one minute:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(HOUR(`date`) < 10 , '0','') , HOUR(`date`)) AS `HH`, (MAX(`total`) - MIN(`total`)) AS `total` 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) `date`, `total`
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
) a GROUP BY `HH`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have as a result of the total different readings .. can you make me understand how the values would be grouped with this query?